# Why does the second expression also evaluate to true in this "switch" statement?

Tags: c++, arduino, switch-statement, expression

I hope some can help me with a beginner question (this is specifically running on Arduino, but I suspect it is a much more fundamental C++ question than that).

I do not understand why the following "switch" statement outputs **both** "Channel 1" and "Channel 2" statements:

```
void setup() {
  delay(100);
  Serial.begin(57600);
  delay(100);

  int channel = 1;

  switch (channel) {
    case 1:
      Serial.println("Channel 1");
    case 2:
      Serial.println("Channel 2");
  }
}

void loop() {

}
```

I have read that the switch statements "follow-though" or "cascade", i.e. I understand that if condition 1 is satisfied then the code will still go on to check the subsequent conditions regardless (and you can add an explicit "break" command to jump out). This is all fine.

But I don't understand that then the second expression evaluates to true (because the integer variable channel=1, and it should only evaluate true when channel=2).

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to `break` the case. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Comment: @teeeeee That's now how C++ is defined to work. You *must* have a `break`. Otherwise case statements *fall through* to the next one below, unconditionally. That should be well-documented in all decent beginners materials.

Comment: `I understand that if condition 1 is satisfied then the code will still go on to check the subsequent conditions` No, it won't check the conditions. It just falls through.

Comment: *and it should only evaluate true when channel=2* -- That is not how the `case` works without a `break`.  If it did what you stated, then there would be no need for the `break`.

Comment: *I understand that if condition 1 is satisfied then the code will still go on to check the subsequent conditions regardless* It doesn't do that, it just goes on running all of the following cases.  It only ever checks for which case statement to start with.

Comment: `case 2` does not evaluate bool values. It's a jump label.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I was completely misunderstanding the behaviour. Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: @273K What do you mean? Do you mean I shouldn't use "int" type? Is there a better way I can do the check, do you think?

Comment: To avoid such bad surprises, I recommend to enable Clang/GCC warning `-Wimplicit-fallthrough`and to use [`[[fallthrough]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough) C++17 attributes in the rare cases where you *actually* wishes fall through.

Comment: Why has this question been closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to expect it to be like

```
if (channel == 1) 
    Serial.println("Channel 1"); 
if (channel == 2) 
   Serial.println("Channel 2");
```

but it's actually like

```
if (channel == 1)
    goto case1;
if (channel == 2)
    goto case2;
goto none;
case1:
    Serial.println("Channel 1");
case2:
    Serial.println("Channel 2")
none:
```

Comment: But in your second example, if I defined channel=1 at the start, it would never print "Channel 1", right? This is not what I observe (I see both statements being printed).

Comment: It would junp to `case1:`, which prints "Channel 1", and continue from there.

Comment: And after jumping to case1, would it then print case2 automatically? (i.e. unconditionally)

Comment: @teeeeee obviously yes... lables are just... lables, they don't do anything by themselves.

Comment: Yes, that's how jumping works.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was misunderstanding from the documentation. I didn't realise the follow-through was unconditional. Cheers for the help.

Comment: It's usually called "fall through", which makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
switch (channel) {
  case 1:
    Serial.println("Channel 1");
  case 2:
    Serial.println("Channel 2");
  case 3:
    Serial.println("Channel 3");
}
```

Is equivalent to this code (which should never be written in the real world):

```
if (channel == 1)
{
  Serial.println("Channel 1");
  goto next_1;
}

if (channel == 2)
{
  next_1:
  Serial.println("Channel 2");
  goto next_2;
}

if (channel == 3)
{
  next_2:
  Serial.println("Channel 3");
}
```

Comment: @teeeeee yes, of course. I have edited.